# Python: XPATH searching within a node

Tags: python, html, xpath

What is a good way to select multiple nodes from with in a node in a html code using xpath?

I have this code (actually this repeated 23 times);

```
<li>
<a class="Title" href="http://www.google.com" >Google</a>
<div class="Info">
    <p>
        text
    </p>

        <p class="Date">Status: Under development</p>

</div>
```

I am trying to get both Title and Date and have two different XPATH querys like this;

```
//a[@class="Title"]/@href
//p[@class="Date"]
```

But when I do this I get two returns with 23 and 22 values each. This is because at one point in the HTML code Date is not present. Therefore I would like to stay inside the li and search for Title and Date within that li so I can check if there are any values.

I changed my XPATH to this;

```
//li
```

In my return Element I can see that there are two sub elements, a and div but I cannot seem to figure out how I am supposed to handle what is inside the return Element?

Comment: I think I might have found out my own answer; I can just jump into to the return element like this; element = tree.xpath('//li') and use element[0][0] ... to navigate within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to search elements within the current node you need to start your Xpath pattern with a dot.

For example:

```
.//a[@class="Title"]/@href
.//p[@class="Date"]
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from without a dot. Can you please explain, I am very new to xpath

Comment: @Niclas When you using //li for example you searching for all the li nodes in the entire document, but if you using .//li you will get all the li nodes that descended from your current node.
I suggest you to go over xpath syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thank you shlomta1, I read through this earlier and again to be certain. However, my problem is not that I am getting results from outside the node but in one place the class="Date" is empty so naturally nothing is returned. I would like to catch this somehow. Running your example would generate two arrays, 23 and 22 long. But I have no way of knowing which pairs match up.

Comment: Oh, so I think that the best solution is to collect all the li nodes, then iterate over them and extract the title and date from each li node separately and put them into tuple or dictionary.

Comment: Thanx shlomta1. I created something like that, checking the length (no. of li) and then performing multiple xpath() querys)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. @Niclas